# Is it possible to enable / disable native automation at testcase level

Tags: testcafe

We have mix of multi-window and non multi-window testcase as part of our suite. Since multi-window is not supported currently with nativeAutomation mode, is it possible to enable/disable at testcase level? (something like passing at meta level etc)